# Many copies of "Applet started" string in java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I created a applet using threads. When i run it and change the size of the window I see a few copies of "Applet started" string. I wonder why is that and how to fix that?

When exactly does this strin starts?
here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class app extends javax.swing.JApplet {

   /**
    * 
    */
   Random generator = new Random();

   public int n = 15;
   public int m = 15;
   public int k = 200;
   public int size = 25;
   public kwadrat[][] watki;
   public double p = 0.98;
   public boolean sth = true ;

   /**
    * Function initializes threads by given data
    * @exception NumberFormatException when there is no data from html code
    * 
    */
   public void init(){


      try{n = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("n"));}
      catch( NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println("Nieprawidłowy parametr: n");
      }
      catch( NullPointerException e){}

      try{m = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("m"));}
      catch( NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println("Nieprawidłowy parametr: m");
      }
      catch( NullPointerException e){}

      try{k = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("k"));}
      catch( NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println("Nieprawidłowy parametr: k");
      }
      catch( NullPointerException e){}

      try{ p = Double.parseDouble(getParameter("p"));}
      catch( NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println("Nieprawidłowy parametr: k");
      }
      catch( NullPointerException e){}

      watki = new kwadrat[n][m];
      for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
      for (int j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j){
         watki[i][j] = new kwadrat(10+i*size,
                                     10+j*size,
                                     i,
                                     j,
                                     size,
                                     (int)(k*(generator.nextDouble()+0.5)),
                                     new java.awt.Color(generator.nextInt(255),
                                                        generator.nextInt(255),
                                                        generator.nextInt(255)
                                                        )
                                     );
      }



   }
   /**
    * start method start the threads
    */
   public void start(){

       for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
       for (int j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j){
         Thread t;
         t = new Thread( new MovingRunnable(watki[i][j]));
         t.start();
      }
   }


   /**
    * Paint method is responsible for drawing the rectangles(threads)
    */
   public void paint(Graphics g){
       //super.paint(g);
       //g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
       repaint();

       for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
       for (int j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j){



         g.setColor(watki[i][j].kwadratColor);

         g.fillRect(watki[i][j].x, watki[i][j].y, size, size);

      }


   }
    /**
     * 
     * @author Seba
     * Class MovingRunnable implements Runnable includes rectangles as threads
     * @param b it is object of kwadrat class
     * @param run()  main method of the class. Changes color of rectangles
     * @exception InterruptedException when something is wrong with sleeping thread
     */
    private class MovingRunnable implements Runnable{
         private final kwadrat b;
         private MovingRunnable(kwadrat b){this.b=b;}
         public void run(){
            for(;;){ 
               if(generator.nextDouble()<p){
                   int c1 = 0,c2 = 0,c3 = 0;

                   if(b.nrx>0){

                       c1 += watki[b.nrx-1][b.nry].kwadratColor.getRed();
                       c2 += watki[b.nrx-1][b.nry].kwadratColor.getGreen();
                       c3 += watki[b.nrx-1][b.nry].kwadratColor.getBlue();

                   }
                   if(b.nrx<n-1) {

                       c1 += watki[b.nrx+1][b.nry].kwadratColor.getRed();
                       c2 += watki[b.nrx+1][b.nry].kwadratColor.getGreen();
                       c3 += watki[b.nrx+1][b.nry].kwadratColor.getBlue();

                   }
                   if(b.nry>0)   {

                       c1 += watki[b.nrx][b.nry-1].kwadratColor.getRed();
                       c2 += watki[b.nrx][b.nry-1].kwadratColor.getGreen();
                       c3 += watki[b.nrx][b.nry-1].kwadratColor.getBlue();

                   }
                   if(b.nry<m-1) {

                       c1 += watki[b.nrx][b.nry+1].kwadratColor.getRed();
                       c2 += watki[b.nrx][b.nry+1].kwadratColor.getGreen();
                       c3 += watki[b.nrx][b.nry+1].kwadratColor.getBlue();

                   }

                   b.changeColor(new java.awt.Color(c1/4,c2/4,c3/4));

               }
               else
                   //b.changeColor(Color.GRAY);
                   b.changeColor(generator);
               repaint();
               try {
               Thread.sleep(b.wait);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
         }
      }
}
/**
 * 
 * @author Seba
 * @param x position in x
 * @param y position in y
 * @param nrx x position in watki[][] array
 * @param nry y position in watki[][] array
 * @param wait time of sleeping thread
 * @param size size of side
 * @param kwadratColor - color of the ractangle
 * @param kwadrat(int,int,int,int,int,int,Color) main constructor 
 * @param changeColor(Random) changing color by generating Random
 * @param changeColor(Color) changing color to given color
 */
class kwadrat{

   public int x;
   public int y;
   public int nrx;
   public int nry;
   public int wait;
   public int size;

   Color kwadratColor;

   public kwadrat( int x, int y, int nrx, int nry, int size , int wait, Color kwadratColor){

      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.nrx = nrx;
      this.nry = nry;
      this.size = size;
      this.kwadratColor = kwadratColor;
      this.wait = wait;

   }

   public void changeColor(Random gen){
       kwadratColor = new java.awt.Color(gen.nextInt(255),
                                         gen.nextInt(255),
                                         gen.nextInt(255)
                                         );
   }

   public void changeColor(Color x){
       kwadratColor = x;
   }


}
```

Comment: Please just post relevant code.

Comment: `catch( NullPointerException e){}` is a bad idea.

Comment: I think `kwadrat` means "square".

Comment: Precisely, kwadrat means "square". Why it is a bad idea?